# Javascript try...catch...else...finally like Python, Java, Ruby, etc

Tags: javascript, try-catch

How can Javascript duplicate the four-part `try`-`catch`-`else`-`finally` execution model that other languages support?

A clear, brief summary is from the [Python 2.5 what's new](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-341-unified-try-except-finally). In Javascript terms:

```
// XXX THIS EXAMPLE IS A SYNTAX ERROR
try {
  // Protected-block
} catch(e) {
  // Handler-block
} else {
  // Else-block
} finally {
  // Final-block
}
```

The code in **Protected-block** is executed. If the code throws an exception, **Handler-block** is executed; If no exception is thrown, **Else-block** is executed.

No matter what happened previously, **Final-block** is executed once the code block is complete and any thrown exceptions handled. Even if there’s an error in **Handler-block** or **Else-block** and a new exception is raised, the code in **Final-block** is still run.

Note that cutting **Else-block** and pasting at the end of **Protected-block** is *wrong*. If an error happens in **Else-block**, it *must not* be handled by **Handler-block**.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Extending the idea of jhs a little, the whole concept could be put inside a function, to provide even more readability:

```
var try_catch_else_finally = function(protected_code, handler_code, else_code, finally_code) {
  try {
    var success = true;
    try {
      protected_code();
    } catch(e) {
      success = false;
      handler_code({"exception_was": e});
    }
    if(success) {
      else_code();
    }
  } finally {
    finally_code();
  }
};
```

Then we can use it like this (very similar to the python way):

```
try_catch_else_finally(function() {
  // protected block
}, function() {
  // handler block
}, function() {
  // else block
}, function() {
  // final-block
});
```

Comment: Totally. I was thinking of doing a quick NPM module to do this. I left this out of my answer because you have be careful since the `this` value will change vs. the simple nested `try`. However my second example also has that error.

Comment: Right. We'd probably want to bind the `this` of the caller to the four callbacks. Let's call it an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: Just happened back across this. Note, in newer versions of JavaScript, the "fat arrow" notation makes the syntax even more readable.

Comment: This works, but you lose control flow. You can't `return` from the try, `continue` loops, etc.

Answer (score 47):

I know this is old, but here is a **pure syntax solution**, which I think is the proper way to go:

```
try {
    // Protected-block
    try {
        // Else-block
    } catch (e) {
        // Else-handler-block
    }
} catch(e) {
    // Handler-block
} finally {
    // Final-block
}
```

The code in **Protected-block** is executed. If the code throws an error, **Handler-block** is executed; If no error is thrown, **Else-block** is executed.

No matter what happened previously, **Final-block** is executed once the code block is complete and any thrown errors handled. Even if there’s an error in **Handler-block** or **Else-block**, the code in **Final-block** is still run.

If an error is thrown in the **Else-block** it is *not* handled by the **Handler-block** but instead by the **Else-handler-block**

And if you know that the **Else-block** will not throw:

```
try {
    // Protected-block
    // Else-block
} catch(e) {
    // Handler-block
} finally {
    // Final-block
}
```

Moral of the story, don't be afraid to indent ;)

*Note:* this works only if the **Else-handler-block** never throws.

Comment: Nice and clean, without incurring additional complexity or dependencies. I like this solution.

Comment: Much better than adding a `success` variable... _unless_ you want any errors raised in the `else` block to bubble up and _not_ be caught by the main handler block, which is what the Python syntax allows. If that's what you need, I don't see any way without some sort of `success` variable.

Comment: Quite late to the party, but this doesn't work for testing.

Comment: This is very similar to how it was in python <2.4 https://stackoverflow.com/a/35505895/5422525

Comment: What is the solution if I want to treat exceptions in the Else-block as fatal?

Answer (score 12):

I know the question is old and answers has already given but I think that my answer is the simplest to get an "else" in javascripts try-catch-block.

```
var error = null;
try {
    /*Protected-block*/
} catch ( caughtError ) {
    error = caughtError; //necessary to make it available in finally-block
} finally {
    if ( error ) {
        /*Handler-block*/
        /*e.g. console.log( 'error: ' + error.message );*/
    } else {
        /*Else-block*/
    }
    /*Final-block*/
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Javascript does not have the syntax to support the no-exception scenario. The best workaround is nested `try` statements, similar to the "legacy" technique from [PEP 341](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0341/)

```
// A pretty-good try/catch/else/finally implementation.
try {
  var success = true;
  try {
    protected_code();
  } catch(e) {
    success = false;
    handler_code({"exception_was": e});
  }
  if(success) {
    else_code();
  }
} finally {
  this_always_runs();
}
```

Besides readability, the only problem is the `success` variable. If `protected_code` sets `window.success = false`, this will not work. A less readable but safer way uses a function namespace:

```
// A try/catch/else/finally implementation without changing variable bindings.
try {
  (function() {
    var success = true;
    try {
      protected_code();
    } catch(e) {
      success = false;
      handler_code({"exception_was": e});
    }
    if(success) {
      else_code();
    }
  })();
} finally {
  this_always_runs();
}
```

Comment: for the first example - you can always use new Boolean() true/false instead of success = false|true - new Boolean() creates boolean object which when compared against existence returns true in contradiction to literal false which when checked for existence will return false

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution if the problem is the common one of not wanting the error callback to be called if there is an uncaught error thrown by the first callback. ... i.e. conceptually you want ...

```
try { 
    //do block 
    cb(null, result);
} catch(err) {
    // err report
    cb(err)
}
```

But an error in the success cb causes the problem of cb getting called a second time.  So instead I've started using

```
try { 
    //do block 
    try { 
        cb(null, result); 
    } catch(err) { 
        // report uncaught error 
    }
} catch(err) {
    // err report
    cb(err)
}
```

which is a variant on @cbarrick's solution.