# Break statement in finally block swallows exception

Tags: python

Consider:

```
def raiseMe( text="Test error" ):
    raise Exception( text )

def break_in_finally_test():
    for i in range(5):
        if i==2:
            try:
                raiseMe()
            except:
                raise
            else:
                print "succeeded!"
            finally:
                print "testing this!"
                break

if __name__=='__main__':
    break_in_finally_test()
```

I expected to see `Exception( "Test error" )` to be raised, but instead only "testing this" is printed. The intention, of course, was to call `raiseMe()` only once, no matter if we succeed or not - but if it raises an exception, I would have wanted to see that!

Why does break swallow the exception that I explicitly raise?

Comment: I'm not sure why exactly that happens (and find it a bit surprising), but you could break inside `else` instead, because in case of exception it will exit from the loop anyway.

Comment: I can understand how `return` in finally works, but with `break` it's just weird. Your example does not cover this, but the method will even continue to execute after the loop!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#finally:

> If finally is present, it specifies a ‘cleanup’ handler. The try clause is 
> executed, including any except and else clauses. If an exception occurs in 
> any of the clauses and is not handled, the exception is temporarily saved. 
> The finally clause is executed. If there is a saved exception, it is 
> re-raised at the end of the finally clause. **If the finally clause raises 
> another exception or executes a return or break statement, the saved 
> exception is discarded**

This also reflects the behaviour expected from the `try...finally` statement before [PEP341](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0341/):

This is how a try except finally block looked like pre PEP341:

```
try:
    try:
        raiseMe()
    except:
        raise
finally:
    #here is where cleanup is supposed to happen before raising error
    break
    #after finally code: raise error
```

As the raising of errors never happens in the `finally` block it is never actually raised.

To maintain backwards compatibility with Python<=2.4, it had to be done in this way.

Comment: Ok, so it _is_ documented. But I have to say that I still find this behaviour really surprising (unlike most python behavior, that is usually so intuitive). My feeling is that Exceptions should "trump" return(s) or break(s)...

Comment: @TimO I agree. I wonder if maybe this was not implemented in this way because they would not have to overwrite the behaviour of break for this particular type of block.

Answer (score 6):

From the docs [Error Handling Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html):

> A finally clause is always executed before leaving the try statement, whether an exception has occurred or not.

Your exception never gets raised because you break before the try statement gets fully evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Have the following code structure:

```
def func():
    try: 
        driver.do("something")
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
    finally:
        result = driver.do("something else")
        return result
```

Got the exception by pylint:

`return statement in finally block may swallow exception (lost-exception)`

Solution was to put return out of the finally statement:

```
def func():
    try: 
        driver.do("something")
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
    finally:
        result = driver.do("something else")
    return result # <<
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* upon reflection that it is due to the fact that break actually raises a StopIteration to "break" out of the for-loop. This is really not very intuitive and not particularly well documented (not mentioned on [1](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), for example). Could maybe someone confirm/explain it better?

Comment: Is this really the case, or just a guess? If this is so, then shouldn't I be able to catch the StopIteration exception caused by break in the loop? Neither does manually raising a StopIteration in a for loop has the same effect.

Comment: @tobias_k It was a - probably wrong - guess. The docs do explain it - see accepted answer.