# How to display something if Catch isn't run?

Tags: javascript, syntax, try-catch

I am wondering how to "do something" only if it passes, like how `catch` is only run if there's an error.
Like in my example, `console.log("FOO")` will not result in an error so the catch will not run but how can I have something *only* run if it's not caught?

```
 try { 
  console.log("FOO")
 }
 catch(err) {
   message.innerHTML = "Input is WRONG";
 }
 message.innerHTML = "Input Works!" // <--- this will always get hit regardless of error or not
```

Comment: If you want it to run only if the `catch` is not executed, put that line of code inside the `try` statement.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/4872170/3001761

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript try...catch...else...finally like Python, Java, Ruby, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872170/javascript-try-catch-else-finally-like-python-java-ruby-etc)

Comment: @JohnNada for future reference, there's no need to put the language in the title of the question -- the language is automatically included with the title on the home page based on the tags you've used.

Comment: @mhodges, code in the `try` block could be run before an Exception is thrown.

Comment: @Aioros I'm not sure what you mean? If you want to try something, and if it's successful, execute a given line(s) of code, you can rely on the synchronicity of the line in question. If the line in question is asynchronous, simply wrapping it in a try/catch will not help you.

Comment: I mean that OP seems to want a way to execute some code only if the previous `try` block was successful. Some code in the `try` block could be executed even if an exception is thrown a little later and catched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your catch to run the try block needs to fail – like in the case of a missing variable.

```js
const messageA = document.querySelector('#message-a');
const messageB = document.querySelector('#message-b');

const a = 10;
const b = 10;  
// const c = 10;
 

//  Test 1 (works)
try {
  let sum = a + b;
  messageA.innerHTML = "We're Happy!"
} catch (err) {
  messageA.innerHTML = "Houston we have a problem!";
}

//  Test 2 (fails because c is not defined)
try {
  let sum = a + c;
  messageB.innerHTML = "We're Happy!"
} catch (err) {
  messageB.innerHTML = "Houston we have a problem!";
}
```

```html
<p>Test 1: <span id="message-a"></span></p>
<p>Test 2: <span id="message-b"></span></p>
```

**The difference between if/else and try/catch**

If/else is a **conditional statement** that *evaluates a condition* e.g.  x == 42
and then run either the true or false block based on the result.

```
if (condition) { 
    /* condition is true do... */
}
else { 
    /* condition is false do... */ 
}
```

Try/catch is an **exception statement** that will always run the try block and only 
transfer control to the catch block if something *causes an error to be thrown* 
(in general a fatal error that will otherwise break the program).

```
try {
    /* do this... and if it fails transfer control to catch */
} 
catch(err) {
    /* something caused an error now do this... */
}
```

Think of it as a method to handle errors – like if you make a request to an api and 
for some reason the server does not respond, you are not authorized or...

**Read more:** [Control flow and error handling on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling)

Comment: so it's basically an `if` `else` ?

Comment: Not exactly, one is a conditional and the other is an exception statement. I've made an attempt to explain the difference in my answer above – hope it makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need something like this:

```
var success = true;
try { 
    console.log("FOO");
}
catch(err) {
    success = false;
}
if (success)
    message.innerHTML = "Input Works!";
else
    message.innerHTML = "Input is WRONG";
```