# JavaScript equivalent for the "else" in try.. except.. else?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I want to generate a file through randomly selecting an index from a list. That works. However, I occasionally get the error: `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

I tried using the `try.. catch` statement but that doesn't quite achieve what I would like.
I'm not familiar with JavaScript, but I know in python I could do something like:

```py
while True:
    # generate the image
    try:
        # do stuff
    except Exception:
        # do nothing so it regenerates an image
    else:
        break
```

This doesn't work in JavaScript, the "else" says it expects a decision.

Comment: So basically just keep trying to generate an image until it succeeds?

Comment: Yeah, basically

Comment: Hey in which case you want to break the loop.

Comment: This gives some related suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872170/javascript-try-catch-else-finally-like-python-java-ruby-etc (and of course if you really want to keep repeating code forever until it succeeds -- or crashes --, you would use a `while` loop, which JavaScript has)

Comment: What are you planning to do when the error happens?  `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` is a browser error, so you cannot `catch` it with Javascript.

Comment: Then I don't have a clue, to be honest

Comment: Not sure what API you are working with for the files, but if it is asynchronous then you should check out promises - they [provide a way to distinguish `except` and `else` cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24663315/1048572) with a dedicated method. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44664037/1048572).