# How to reproduce this rollover effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

[This website](https://www.eastlondonmosque.org.uk/)'s nav bar has a nice, smooth rollover effect that I like. As far as I can tell, it's being done in JavaScript - can such a thing be easily emulated with CSS, and if so, how would I apply it to my own website's navigation?

I've looked for CSS examples, but nothing I've found quite comes close to the cascade-like effect that this website's menu has, and adapting what I have found to my (Wordpress) site just breaks my navigation.

The slow slide back when the site's sub-menu item loses focus would also be a massive bonus. If the effects can't be emulated to the same degree of smoothness in CSS, I'm happy to be directed to a JavaScript solution/library that I won't have to pay for.

Here's the markup for my site's navigation:

```
<nav class="main-navigation">
  <ul id="primary-menu" class="primary-menu menu">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/about">About</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/about/history/">History</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/about/people">People</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Services</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/what-we-do">What We Do</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/the-library/">The Library</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/the-library/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item" class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/audio-and-video/">Audio and Video</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/donate/">Donate</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/contact/">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And here is most of the CSS relating to it:

```
.primary-menu,
.primary-menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.primary-menu {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: calc(var(--menuItemsSpacing) / -2);
    margin-right: calc(var(--menuItemsSpacing) / -2);
}

.primary-menu a {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: initial;
    overflow: none;
    color: #000;
}

.primary-menu .current-menu-item a {
    color:#FFF;
    background-color: #09153F;
}

.primary-menu>li {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 400;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.primary-menu>li a {
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: color, background-color;
    transition-property: color, background-color; 
}

.primary-menu>li:hover a,
.primary-menu>li:focus a,
.primary-menu>li:active a {
    background-color: #09153F;
    color: #FFF;

}

.primary-menu .sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: var(--dropdownTopOffset);
    min-width: 100%;
    width:120%;
    display:block;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: #09153F;
}

.primary-menu .sub-menu li {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: initial;
    line-height: 1.6;
}

.primary-menu .sub-menu li a {
    transition: padding 0.2s ease-out;
}

.primary-menu .sub-menu li a:hover {
    padding-left:30px;
    color: var(--menuHoverColor);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript try...catch...else...finally like Python, Java, Ruby, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872170/javascript-try-catch-else-finally-like-python-java-ruby-etc)

Comment: You don't need JS to reproduce this.

Answer (score -1):

Look into CSS transitions.

Here is an example.
ul.topLevel li {
 transition:all .6s ease-out
}
ul.topLevel li:hover {
 transition:all .2s ease-out
}

Edit:

```
As per the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/toddsynan/pen/pJuyx) all that is needed is transitions.

.nav2 li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 36px;
    z-index: 1;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transition: 200ms ease;
    -moz-transition: 200ms ease;
    -o-transition: 200ms ease;
    transition: 200ms ease;
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of CSS transitions. As already mentioned in my question, the ones I've come across don't come close to emulating the smoothness of the one I've seen on this site, and besides that, applying them to my navigation breaks it. If you know of a CSS transition that replicates the same level of smoothness and also won't break my site's navigation, feel free to recommend one.

Comment: As I mentioned, look into transitions. If transitions break your menu then you aren't applying it right.

All you need to do is play around with it to get the desired feel you are after.

Transitions have so many options. 

As for the JS on that site - all it does to the menu is change display none to display block.

Comment: Did you get your issue sorted?